# Show a remote URL as popup in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome addon and I need to show a remote URL as a popup. I have tried the following in `manifest.json`.

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_title" : "Pennyful",
    "default_popup" : "http://www.google.com"
}
```

This was not working. So I handled the event and set the popup from code.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "http://www.google.com"});
});
```

This also didn't work. I have also tried creating a `html` page packaged with the addon, and when loaded does a JS redirect to the remote website. This didn't work. Then I put a `iframe` inside the page and set the remote URL as source to the `iframe`. In this case iframe shows up, but it takes long time to load the page and the width is incorrect.

So it looks like there is no way to set a remote URL as a popup page. I'm wondering is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In short, **no**, you can't just open an external website without using an `iframe` into your `popup.html` file.

This [Google Developer Codelabs article](https://sites.google.com/site/gdevelopercodelabs/chrome-extensions/codelab) goes through how to use external service APIs (like Twitter or Flickr) to display information *from* another site in your popup. That might be the way to go if an `iframe` doesn't work for what you're trying to do.